# unexpected result from skip in read.csv

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to read a csv into R skipping the first 2 rows. The csv is a mixture of blanks, text data and numeric data where the thousand separator is ",".

The file reads into R fine (gives a 31 x 27 df), but when i change the argument to include skip = 2 it returns a single column with 282 observations.

I have tried it using the readr package's read_csv function and it works fine.

> testdf <- read.csv("test.csv")

works fine - gives a dataframe of 31 obs of 27 variables

I get the following error message when trying to use the skip argument:

> testdf <- read.csv("test.csv", skip = 2)
>   Warning message:
>   In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
>     EOF within quoted string

which results in a single variable with 282 observations

Comment: You can't delete the row after importing the csv?

Comment: yes but it's not ideal, i want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: after reading the data with `testdf <- read.csv("test.csv")` can you post `head(dput(testdf))` ?

Comment: that's quite long, it's basically printed the whole table, with labels - was that the expected behaviour?

Comment: sorry, I meant `dput(head(testdf))`